# How to set statuscode on postman throw exeption java

Tags: java, controller, throw

i have this snippet , in my controller

```
public String getlavoro(String nome , String cognome) throws Exception {
        if (determinareSeEUnaStringaONo(nome)== false && determinareSeEUnaStringaONo(cognome) == false){
            List<Cliente> cliente =clienteRepository.findByNomeAndCognome(nome,cognome);
            if (cliente.size() != 0){
                Cliente c = cliente.get(0);
                Optional<Lavoro> lavoro = lavoroRepository.findByIdcliente(Math.toIntExact(c.getId()));
                return "nome : "+c.getNome()+" cognome "+c.getCognome()+" lavoro :"+ lavoro.get().getNomelavoro();
            }else
                throw new  // insert status code 404 
        throw new //  insert status code 400
    }
```

basically i have to set statuscode on postman throw exeption , i can i write it ? i have to change to specific status this on postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mQwZ.png)

Comment: You have to use `ResponseEntity<>` for send message in postman. See Here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity#:~:text=ResponseEntity%20represents%20the%20whole%20HTTP,takes%20care%20of%20the%20rest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a mapping between your *custom exception* and your *http code*, in a [ControllerAdvice](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-restcontrolleradvice/) class.

- `BadRequestException` map to `400` http code
- `RecordNotFoundException` map to `404` http code